# How can i hide the border for qtreeview?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtreeview, qtreewidget, qtstylesheets

I want to hide the border of the QTreeWidget i´m customizing.

I want it to be the same when i select an item inside. But this special outline doesn´t work at all. I want it to be the same as the first image.

[image]

[image]

I use this piece of css code:

```
QTreeView  {
    show-decoration-selected: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

QTreeView::item:selected
{
    background-color: #00CDDF;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
}


QTreeView::branch:selected {
    background-color: #00CDDF;
    outline: none
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Border and outline are different things. Look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp). `Outline` is separate property which is set to `none` by default. The visible line around your `QTreeView` is `border` property which has some default value.

If  you want to remove border, try to set border property like [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview).

```
QTreeView {
     border: none;
}
```

For removing border on specific side,

```
QTreeView {
     border: 1px solid;
     border-top: none;
}
```

For selected item you can use this selector, `QTreeView::item`, for active item(s) `QTreeView::item:selected:active` and for selected item(s) `QTreeView::item:selected`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
QTreeView
{
  border: none;
}
```

or

```
QTreeView > QScrollArea
{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Wow. what is  QTreeView > QScrollArea?
is it the same as 
QScrollArea QTreeView {} ?

Comment: Nop. QTreeView contains QScrollArea inside of it.

Comment: Sorry. i mean,  QTreeView QScrollArea means a scroll area inside the tree view. Why use > ?

Comment: You can read about selectors there: [link](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types)

Comment: Oh thanks Dmitry. So they are direct descendants. Not necessary, but interesting. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

For selected items following works better for me:

```
  QString style = "QTreeWidget::item:!selected "
    "{ "
      "border: 1px solid gainsboro; "
      "border-left: none; "
      "border-top: none; "
    "}"
    "QTreeWidget::item:selected {}";
  treeWidget->setStyleSheet(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

For selected items such style-sheet works better for me:

```
  QString style = "QTreeWidget::item:!selected "
    "{ "
      "border: 1px solid gainsboro; "
      "border-left: none; "
      "border-top: none; "
    "}"
    "QTreeWidget::item:selected {}";
  allergiesListView->setStyleSheet(style);
```